# React-Konva get node absolute x and y

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-konva

I am trying to get the absolute position of a drawn node.

The Konva docs show that it's possible to find a node with:

```
   // select node with id foo
   var node = stage.find('#foo');
```

And though it might help, but I couldn't find a way to access `stage` if I am not interacting directly with the Stage. Is there any way to get the stage from "outside" or to get the position of a certain node in respect to the entire view?

Thanks

Comment: What is "outside"? Canvas component? Do you have access to any nodes?

Comment: By outside I meant a totally different component

Comment: But is it still a canvas component? Do you have access to any konva nodes?